# Flattening tables in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using BigQuery to flatten GA data and it worked fine, in last 2 months we get much less data with flattening. If we calculate just sessions from a field `SUM(totals.visits) as Sessions` we would get correct number, but when flattened we get around 50% less. Has anybody had something similar

This is how we flatten:

```
FROM
  FLATTEN(FLATTEN( (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        TABLE_DATE_RANGE ([96790097.ga_sessions_],
          TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -1, "DAY")),
          TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()))),
      customDimensions),
    hits)
```

Comment: Do you have any nested repeated fields? If you flatten them it will not retain the full data.

You probably want to explore using `UNNEST` instead.

If you can provide an example of your data schema and your desired output we will be able to assist better.

Resources: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/legacy-nested-repeated#flatten, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays

Comment: I thought UNNEST and FLATTEN are the same depending on using legacy or standard sql. we still use legacy, therefor UNNEST. yes we have fields from customDimension and hits used in query, therefor two flatten function. schema is ga_sessions same as in bigquery export schema

Comment: In terms of getting this answered, the most helpful thing to do would be to post some example data or a schema. I am not familiar with the default `ga_sessions` export.